# Vuejs 3 using i18n translation inside "script setup>

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a Laravel + Inertiajs + Vue 3  with Vite

I user Quasar framework so in one vue file I have a Quasar table.
Now I need to translate the column labels.

```
<template>
    <head title="Elenco utenti"></head>

    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
          <div>
            <q-toolbar class="q-gutter-sm">
              <Link :href="route('list-utenti')" type="button" class="float-right"><q-btn flat round dense icon="people" /></Link>
              <div class="text-subtitle1">{{ $t('utenti.pagetitle')}}</div>
            </q-toolbar>
          </div>
        </template>

        <div class="q-py-md q-gutter-sm">
          <Link :href="route('register')" type="button" class="float-right"><q-btn icon="add_box" color="white" text-color="text-grey-7" :label="$t('utenti.btn_new')"></q-btn></Link>
        </div>
        <div class="q-py-xl">
          <q-table
            title=""
            :rows="users"
            :columns="columns"
            row-key="id"
          >
            <template v-slot:body-cell-actions="props">
              <q-td :props="props">
                <q-btn icon="mode_edit" @click="onEdit(props.row)"></q-btn>
                <q-btn icon="person_off" @click="onDelete(props.row)"></q-btn>
              </q-td>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:body-cell-email="props">
              <q-td :props="props">
                <strong>{{ props.value }} </strong>
              </q-td>
            </template>          
          </q-table>
        </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

As you can see in the template code, I configured i18n and I can correctly translate with {{ $t('utenti.pagetitle') }} when in template.

now this is the script part

```
<script setup>
  import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
  import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';
  import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
  import { computed, ref} from '@vue/reactivity';
  import { Quasar, useQuasar } from 'quasar';

  const props = defineProps({
      page_description : String,
      title: String,
      numero_record: Number,
      users: Array
  });

  const columns = [
    {
      name: 'id',
      required: true,
      label: 'id',
      align: 'left',
      field: row => row.id,
      format: val => `${val}`,
      sortable: false
    },
    { name: 'name', align: 'left', label: translated_name, field: 'name', sortable: true},
    { name: 'email', align: 'left', label: 'e-mail', field: 'email', sortable: false},
    { name: 'ruolo', align: 'left', label: 'ruolo', field: 'ruolo', sortable: true},
    { name: 'listino_grossista_visible', align: 'center', label: 'list. grossista', field: 'listino_grossista_visible', sortable: true},
    { name: 'enabled', align: 'center', label: 'Attivo', field: 'enabled', sortable: true},
    { name: 'actions', align: 'center', label: 'Azioni'}
  ]

  const onEdit = (row) => {
    Inertia.post(route('edit-utente'),
      { row } ,
      { onBefore: () => confirm('Vuoi veramente modificarlo?')}
    )
  }

  const onDelete = (row) => {
    alert('DELETE ' + row.email);
  }
</script>
```

I would like to use in some way $t to get the correct translation for the grid columns labels (for example 'translated_name' but I don' understand how I can do it as it is in the script part and I can not use same as in template.

I probably understood that I need to add some computed properties but I didn't exactly figured out how. Consider I'm using composition api.

```
  const translated_name = computed(() =>  {
    return $t('utenti.nome')
  })
```

I checked also this link [Vue-i18n not translating inside component script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731110/vue-i18n-not-translating-inside-component-script-tags) but I didn't understood how to adapt to my case.

kind regards,
Matt

Comment: computed property worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and fixed it like this:

```
import { QTableColumn } from 'quasar';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
const { t } = useI18n(({ useScope: 'global' })); //global since my language switch is in another component.

const columns = 
computed<QTableColumn[]>(() => [{
  name: 'object_id',
  align: 'left',
  label: t('table_id'),
  field: row => row.id,
  sortable: true
}, {
  name: 'object_name',
  align: 'left',
  label: t('table_name'),
  field: row => row.name,
  sortable: true
}]);
```

I had some issues with the `:columns: 'columns'` giving a type error.
As such, it's a typed computed: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-computed

For searchability, when computed is not typed it gives the following error:
`The expected type comes from property 'columns' which is declared here on type 'VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & QTableProps & Record<string, unknown>'`